# Full screen preview Android camera2

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2, android-textureview

I'm building my own camera using google example: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic . The problem is that this camera is not fullscreen,i've tryed with this changes in this metod:

```
   private void setUpCameraOutputs(int width, int height) {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            for (String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
                CameraCharacteristics characteristics
                        = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

                // We don't use a front facing camera in this sample.
                Integer facing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
                if (facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
                    continue;
                }

                StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(
                        CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
                if (map == null) {
                    continue;
                }

                // For still image captures, we use the largest available size.
                Size largest = Collections.max(
                        Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)),
                        new CompareSizesByArea());
                mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(),
                        ImageFormat.JPEG, /*maxImages*/2);
                mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(
                        mOnImageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);

                // Find out if we need to swap dimension to get the preview size relative to sensor
                // coordinate.
                int displayRotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                //noinspection ConstantConditions
                mSensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
                boolean swappedDimensions = false;
                switch (displayRotation) {
                    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                        if (mSensorOrientation == 90 || mSensorOrientation == 270) {
                            swappedDimensions = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                        if (mSensorOrientation == 0 || mSensorOrientation == 180) {
                            swappedDimensions = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.e(TAG, "Display rotation is invalid: " + displayRotation);
                }

                Point displaySize = new Point();
                activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(displaySize);
                int maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.x;
                int maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.y;


               /* if (maxPreviewWidth > MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH) {
                    maxPreviewWidth = MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH;
                }

                if (maxPreviewHeight > MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT) {
                    maxPreviewHeight = MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT;
                }*/

                // Danger, W.R.! Attempting to use too large a preview size could  exceed the camera
                // bus' bandwidth limitation, resulting in gorgeous previews but the storage of
                // garbage capture data.
                /*mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                        rotatedPreviewWidth, rotatedPreviewHeight, maxPreviewWidth,
                        maxPreviewHeight, largest);*/

                mPreviewSize=new Size(maxPreviewHeight,maxPreviewWidth);
                // We fit the aspect ratio of TextureView to the size of preview we picked.
                mTextureView.setAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());

                // Check if the flash is supported.
                Boolean available = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE);
                mFlashSupported = available == null ? false : available;

                mCameraId = cameraId;
                return;
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // Currently an NPE is thrown when the Camera2API is used but not supported on the
            // device this code runs.
            ErrorDialog.newInstance(getString(R.string.camera_error))
                    .show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
        }
    }
```

But the preview is distorted. How can I get a full-screen preview with the only button on it?

Comment: you have to make the activity full screen in your manifest.

Comment: @SripadRaj i add  
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"> in the manifest,but nothing change